# Restsrict LDAP Group CentOS 7

Tags: centos, group, ldap, openldap

Setting up LDAP Login was easy enough for me using the following...

```
yum -y install openldap-clients nss-pam-ldapd git
Basic Configuration

authconfig --enableldap \
--enableldapauth \
--ldapserver={ldap.domain.com,192.168.1.255} \
--ldapbasedn="dc=domain,dc=com" \
--enablemkhomedir \
--update
```

But I can't get LDAP group restrictions to work, which is kinda paramount, I don't want the entire company getting access, just like 5 people. Im using CentOS 7 fully updated.

Answer (score 0):

In the sssd.conf, under the correct domain, add the ldap_access_filter. e.g.

```
access_provider = ldap
ldap_access_filter = memberOf=cn=Group Name,ou=Groups,dc=example,dc=com
```

Comment: I'm not using SSSD, but I will give it another shot, I had trouble with SSSD, but the above worked and was extremely easy to setup.

Comment: What if there is no `memberOf` attribute? I don't have it. I only have the groups (`cn=groupname` with a `member` attribute for every member).